# Фон блока в форме параллелограма

Tags: css, html5, svg

Нужно сделать фон в форме параллелограмма, как на этой картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать это?

Нужно чтобы работало в браузерах `IE11`, `Mozilla`, `Opera`, `Edge`, `Chrome`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще как вариант можно использовать 2d трансформации:

```css
.block
{
  width: 90vw;
  height: 80vh;
  transform:skewY(-5deg);
  margin: 40px auto;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Для этих целей можно использовать `clip-path`**

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 606 256" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
   <defs>
   <clipPath id="Cp"> 
    <path d="M0.5 38.1 595.7 3.1V218.9L0 256Z" style="fill:none;stroke:#000"/>
    </clipPath>
     
    </defs>   

 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOhFs.jpg" clip-path="url(#Cp)" height="100%" width="100%"/>
  
</svg>
```

**Или маску**

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 606 256" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
   <defs>
   <mask id="msk1"> 
     <rect fill="black" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <path fill="white" d="M0.5 38.1 595.7 3.1V218.9L0 256Z" />
    </clipPath>
     
    </defs>   

 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOhFs.jpg" mask="url(#msk1)" height="100%" width="100%"/>
  
</svg>
```

**Оба варианта адаптивны и работают во всех современных браузерах, включая IE**

Answer (score 3):

Кстати, хочу отметить, что вариант **@Alexandr_TT** работает ещё и через CSS, благодаря свойству `clip-path`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://artescapesonoma.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/abstract-art-background-370799.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
  position: relative;
}

.clip-path {
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1020315/pexels-photo-1020315.jpeg') no-repeat center center / cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  /* Clip Path */
  clip-path: url(#Cp);
}

.hideSVG {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="clip-path"></div>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 606 256" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="hideSVG">
   <defs>
   <clipPath id="Cp"> 
    <path d="M0.5 38.1 595.7 3.1V218.9L0 256Z" style="fill:none; stroke:#000;" />
    </clipPath>
     
    </defs>
</svg>
```

[О свойстве](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

[image: Поддержка]

[Поддержка](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)

Comment: я поленился написать вариант с CSS.  так что благодарность вам (+) Но справедливости ради стоит отметить, что этот вариант  **не адаптивен и не работает в IE**, отражается прямоугольник, вместо параллелограмма

Comment: IE скоро умрет, Microsoft в следующем браузере переходят на новый движок

Comment: @L.F.C. я в большей части имел ввиду `Edge`, но как заявил их топ манагер они и в ближайщем будущем не будут и не собираются поддерживать и ещё много чего вкусного,кроме `clip-path`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT в любом случае, как ни крути, пока все эти изменения не произошли, необходимо и дальше мучиться с этими недобраузерами