# Фон блока формой трапеции

Tags: html, css, svg

Нужен блок с фоном в форме трапеции как на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И нужно чтобы отображалось корректно в браузерах IE11, Mozilla, Opera, Edge, Chrome
Как это сделать?

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/937959/262779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как обычно ...делается это в SVG создаётся pattern внутри image делаем нужную фигура и на фон ставим тот pattern и всё

[codepen.io/pen](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/pGbYed) на случай если картинка не отобразится

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 323 106" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none">
 <defs>
  <pattern id="pattern" width="1228.5714" height="504.28573" patternTransform="matrix(.28 0 0 .4 -115 84)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <image x="-1.6e-14" y="9.3e-14" width="1229" height="504" style="image-rendering:optimizeQuality" preserveAspectRatio="none"
   xlink:href="http://image2.thematicnews.com/uploads/topics/preview/00/08/44/33/79079f9c97.jpg"/>
  </pattern>
 </defs>
 <g transform="translate(115 -84)">
  <path d="m-115 84h323v88l-323 18z" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:url(#pattern);"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```